# vueJS 3.x composition API: why is v-model property conveyed to component empty?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component, `PageModal`, which you can peruse here:

https://github.com/kodecharlie/v3-page-helpers/blob/main/src/components/PageModal.vue

When I include this component in a view that uses the options API, stuff works.
When I include this component in a view that uses the composition API, the v-model attribute passed into `PageModal` is undefined.

Here are the code snippets from my view that uses composition API.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <PageModal v-model="activeModal" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PageModal from '@/components/PageModal.vue';

export default {
  name: "MyCustomComponent",
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => null
    }
  },
  components: { PageModal },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  setup(props) {
    const activeModal = computed({
      iconName: 'exclamation-triangle-fill',
      hasCancelBtn: false,
      okBtnCallback: () => startOver(),
      title: 'Operation failed.',
      bodyMsg: 'Operation failed. Please try again."
    });
    ...
    return { activeModal };
  }
};
</script>
```

Error:

```
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ref'); stack=TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ref')
```

which triggers at this line in `PageModal.vue`:

```
    onMounted(() => {
      activeModal.value.ref = activeModalRef.value;
    });
```

In my views in which `PageModal` works, I export `activeModal` in the options API with the standard `data` method:

```
  data() {
    return {
      activeModal: {
        iconName: 'exclamation-triangle-fill',
        hasCancelBtn: false,
        okBtnCallback: () => startOver(),
        title: 'Operation failed.',
        bodyMsg: 'Operation failed. Please try again."
      }
    };
  }
```

How can this issue be resolved in the composition API?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can't be sure if the input variable is a ref. You can use [`unref()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#unref) to optionally unpack it. Throwing in a check never hurts either:

```
const unpackedModal = unref(activeModal)
if (unpackedModal) {
  unpackedModal.ref = activeModalRef.value;
}
```

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work, so I just reverted to options API, and stuff worked fine.  My concern for programmers broadly is this:  we should be able to seamlessly incorporate components into other components; but the composition API presents special challenges like this which are not at all straightforward to resolve.  This is not the first time I've run into hitches with the composition API.

Comment: You use the ref in the template, so Vue unpacks it automatically. I wasn't sure what else you do with the `activeModal`, but just removing the `.value` should have done the trick. But yes, keeping track of when you are dealing with a ref can be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I think ref couldn't found in mounted..
You should do this.

```js
    onMounted(() => {
      activeModal.value = activeModalRef.value;
    });
```